# center div in div that contains several divs

Tags: css

I am having a similar issues with multiple "contents" in the container. I would like to make the cataloglist-div centered in the inside div, being the width of the inside items.

HTML:

> ```
> <div id="container">
>   <section id="main"> 
>   <div class="inside">
>       <article id="liste" class="mod_article block"> 
>       <div class="mod_cataloglist block">
>           <div class="layout_simple">
>               <div class="item first even">
>                   <div class="item odd">
>                   </div>
>                   <div class="item even">
>                   </div>
>                   <div class="item odd">
>                   </div>
>                   <div class="item even">
>                   </div>
>               </div>
>       </article> 
>   </div>
>   <div class="insidebottom">
>   </div>
>   <div id="clear">
>   </div>
>   </section> 
> </div>
> ```

CSS where I try out several thing, but none of them work:

> ```
>     #main .inside {
>     display: block;
>     float: left;
>     margin-left: auto;
>     margin-right: auto;
>     min-height: 350px;
>     padding-left: 40px;
>     padding-right: 40px;
> }
>
> #main .mod_article {
>     float: left;
> }
> .block {
>     overflow: hidden;
> }
>
> .mod_cataloglist::after {
>     clear: both;
> }
> .mod_cataloglist {
>     clear: both;
>     display: block;
>     float: left;
>     margin-left: auto;
>     margin-right: auto;
> }
>
> .mod_cataloglist .layout_simple::after {
>     clear: both;
> }
> .mod_cataloglist .layout_simple {
>     display: block;
>     overflow: hidden;
> }
> ```

Thanks for any advice

Comment: can u show the screenshot of current state

Comment: I see some closing DIV tags are missing. A working example in fiddle could help to understand the issue exactly.

Comment: I have updated ur code here in the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/NayanaDas/s4LjL04p/, u didnt close 2 divs.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.mod_article` is `float:left`. You can't be centering a div inside an article that doesn't have a defined width. Float left makes it act like an inline element, taking the width of its children.

So your article tag will try to minimize its width, while being pushed as far left as it can go inside its parent element. So trying to center anything inside of that wouldn't work because the article has to be larger than its children to need centering in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

divCeption!

Here are a few examples of ways to center divs, including `display: flex` (whose children can be centered with `margin: auto`), `display: table` (whose children can `vertical-align` *their* children, who can then in turn be horizontally centered with `margin: 0 auto`). Note some of these solutions are `div` specific, such as horizontal centering with `margin: 0 auto`; this is due to their default `display: block` behavior - if we instead used `display: inline-block` on the `.deep` elements, they could be horizontal centered with `text-align: center` like the characters inside of them.

```css
.cont {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.item {
  display: inline-table;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  background: pink;
}

.inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.deep {
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="deep">h</div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="deep">i</div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="deep">!</div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, thanks all for your great comments. I could solve it with the flex command. I got inspired by this example:
http://codepen.io/HugoGiraudel/pen/LklCv

> ```
> .flex-container {
>   padding: 0;
>   margin: 0;
>   list-style: none;
>
>   display: -webkit-box;
>   display: -moz-box;
>   display: -ms-flexbox;
>   display: -webkit-flex;
>   display: flex;
>
>   -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
>   justify-content: space-around;
> }
> ```